# Array antenna gain expectation

Tags: antenna

Should I expect 28 dBi gain if I design properly 2x2 microstrip patch antenna array in which an element has 7 dBi gain? Or expectations should be 10-11 dBi?

Comment: where do you take the 28 dBi from?

Comment: 28 dBi is not how combining logs works. Maybe 10-12  - just maybe more with properly designed array.

Answer (score 1):

Given you have 4 identical antennas, your array will gather 4x the energy (at best), so expect 3 + 3 dB more output power.